# Emberjs: how to iterate over tweets and display date only when different from the last?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember, so please forgive if this question has been covered elsewhere.

Here's a simplified version of the markup I'm trying to get:

```
<h1>Date1</h1>
<div>Tweet 1 on Date1</div>
<div>Tweet 2 on Date1</div>
<h1>Date2</h1>
<div>Tweet 3 on Date2</div>
<div>Tweet 4 on Date2</div>
```

I come from django, so i'm used to the `ifchanged` tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

What's the right way to get this?  I looked into handlebars helpers, but they appear to be stateless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Handlebars is far too logicless to accomplish such a task. You will need to have this sorted out, before you hand it to the template.

This could be one way to solve it, say you have a TweetsController of the type ArrayController. You could then make a computed property that would traverse your array, and return a filtered version.

```
noRepeatedDates: function() {
  var tweets = [];

  var lastTweet = Ember.Object.create();

  this.get('model').forEach(function(tweet) {
    if(tweet.get('date') == lastTweet.get('date')) {
      tweet.set('date', undefined);
    } else {
      lastTweet = tweet   
    }
    tweets.pushObject(tweet);
  }); 

  return tweets;
}.property('@each')
```

I did't test this code, generally the purpose is to give you an idea of how to think, when using handlebars.

But with this, you should be able to traverse the noRepeatedDates in your template. Hope i helps.

Comment: Thats an interesting way to do it.  I'm really hoping there is a way to do this where I don't have to put display logic in the controller.

Comment: As a alternative, you could create a a view, and do somewhat the same.